# DXF format using AcDb3dPolyline

Tags: dxf

I need help understanding what is wrong with the DXF file below.  I get an error when I attempt to import this into two separate software products (small and relatively unknown).  I am developing a program to write DXF files and just need to know the correct syntax.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```css
0
SECTION
  2
ENTITIES
  0
POLYLINE
  5
76
330
1F
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDb3dPolyline
 66
     1
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
 30
0.0
 70
     8
  0
VERTEX
  5
77
330
76
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbVertex
100
AcDb3dPolylineVertex
 10
-2.682663316582904
 20
235.6055276381909
 30
0.0
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  5
78
330
76
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbVertex
100
AcDb3dPolylineVertex
 10
11.74257787156506
 20
173.1071513625327
 30
0.0
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  5
79
330
76
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbVertex
100
AcDb3dPolylineVertex
 10
135.7183417085427
 20
173.1798994974874
 30
0.0
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  5
7A
330
76
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbVertex
100
AcDb3dPolylineVertex
 10
-133.6656858850508
 20
97.48688849752057
 30
20.0
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  5
7B
330
76
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbVertex
100
AcDb3dPolylineVertex
 10
-80.43453010615633
 20
72.80698900003313
 30
20.0
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  5
7C
330
76
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbVertex
100
AcDb3dPolylineVertex
 10
220.3247608051047
 20
40.44340560335991
 30
0.0
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  5
7D
330
76
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbVertex
100
AcDb3dPolylineVertex
 10
123.620351758794
 20
47.36080402010046
 30
0.0
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  5
7E
330
76
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbVertex
100
AcDb3dPolylineVertex
 10
30.22386934673369
 20
62.8462311557789
 30
0.0
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  5
7F
330
76
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbVertex
100
AcDb3dPolylineVertex
 10
-35.5891959798995
 20
146.0804020100502
 30
0.0
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  5
80
330
76
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbVertex
100
AcDb3dPolylineVertex
 10
-38.49271356783919
 20
251.5748743718593
 30
0.0
 70
    32
  0
SEQEND
  5
81
330
76
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
  0
ENDSEC
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: @Rowdy Bristol, if Brett's answer solved your problem, make sure you click on the checkmark next to it to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

A DXF file has to end with the End Of File code pair, which you are lacking:

```
  0
EOF
```

In case you don't have it already, here's a [PDF link](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2014_pdf_dxf_reference_enu.pdf) to Autodesk's latest official DXF spec.

Comment: Thanks very much, Brett - that was it!